# How to mock getResourceAsStream method using PowerMockito and JUnit?

Tags: junit, powermock, powermockito

I try to mock `getResourceAsStream` method which I invoke in constructor.

```
public Conn() {
    stream = Conn.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH);
}
```

For mock framework I prefer Mockito + PowerMockito.

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(Conn.class)
    public class ConnTest {

        @Mock
        private InputStream streamMock;

        private Conn conn;

        @Before
        public void before() {
            initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {    
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Conn.class);
            PowerMockito.when(Connector.class.getResourceAsStream("/prop.properties")).thenReturn(streamMock);
            conn = new Conn();
        }

        @After
        public void after() {
            reset(streamMock);
        }
     }
```

But method `thenReturn` doesn't return a mock. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract getting the resource to a class.

```
class StreamFetcher {

InputStream fetchStream(String path) {
return StreamFetcher.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
}

}
```

and in your class

```
class Conn {
public Conn(StreamFetcher streamFetcher) {
    stream = streamFetcher.fetchStream(PATH);
}
}
```

That way you don't even have to do a mock - you can create your own impl for tests that does whatever you need it to do.

Also you can actually abstract more and maybe process the Stream somehow. I don't know the business context so can't really help you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return a mock because the code-under-test `new Conn()` does not call

```
Connector.class.getResourceAsStream(...)
```

it calls

```
Conn.class.getResourceAsStream(...)
```

Your code worked by changing the method stubbing to:

```
PowerMockito.when(Conn.class.getResourceAsStream("/prop.properties")).thenReturn(streamMock);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(Class.class)
    public class ConnTest {

        @Mock
        private InputStream streamMock;

        private Conn conn;

        @Before
        public void before() {
            initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {    
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class.class);
            PowerMockito.when(Connector.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/prop.properties")).thenReturn(streamMock);
            conn = new Conn();
        }

        @After
        public void after() {
            reset(streamMock);
        }
     }
```

Here you are stubbing resource on top of a class object, that is why `Class.class` you need to prepare for test by using `@PrepareForTest(Class.class)` and `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class.class);`.

I am not sure whether it'll work for constructor or not but for a method which is calling `getClass.getResourceAsStream("anyString")` it's working fine(I have tested).